# Vim colorscheme c++

Tags: syntax-highlighting

How do I get a colorscheme such as this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Hello_World_Perl_GTk2.png in gVim?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, as gvim and vim share their configuration files you create directory "colors" in `~/.vim` and put `your_favorite_colorscheme.vim` in it.

Then edit your `.vimrc` file in your home directory with to include this line: `colorscheme your_favorite_colorscheme`

Here's a nice site to check different themes out:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/vimcolorschemetest/

Comment: awesome site! If anyone finds the colorscheme I posted the image of, please post. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `colorscheme your_favorite_colorscheme`? I.e. drop the `.vim` extension.

Comment: The link is broken.